# get mergedProperties of sys_file_reference in tx_news

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I am using TYPO3 9.5.26 with tx_news 8.5.2. I have extended sys_file_reference with my own field. I can access this fields value in my fluid templates like so:

```
{file.properties.tx_myext_frame}
```

This is tested and works fine. However in the news module this stays empty

```
{mediaElement.properties.tx_myext_frame}
```

How can I use the orginalFile properties in tx_news?

Thanks

Code I use to add the field:

typo3conf\ext\myext\ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE sys_file_reference (
    tx_myext_frame tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);
```

typo3conf\ext\myext\Configuration\TCA\Overrides\sys_file_reference.php

```
// Add some fields to sys_file_reference table
$temporaryColumns = [
    'tx_myext_frame' => [
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_frame',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'check',
            'default' => '0',
        ]
    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
    'sys_file_reference',
    'imageoverlayPalette',
    '--linebreak--,tx_myext_invert,tx_myext_frame',
    'after:description'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer myself just now - so for anyone trying this use

```
{mediaElement.originalResource.properties.tx_myext_frame}
```